# How do I solve Statistics Hypothesis Test and Pvalue

Tags: statistics

I was given a random sample, these are the values I got. I Need help with the Hypotheses and P value. Mean:3.1; Standard Deviation:.694; random sample:25

Perform a test of the hypotheses H0:µ=2.5 versus Ha:µ≠2.5 Calculate the P-value.

Comment: IS the Standard Deviation $694$ , or maybe $6.94$? $694$ seems high in relation to the mean of $3.1$.

Comment: standard deviation is .694

Comment: I see. How about the confidence level?

Comment: sorry is that needed for this portion? the next question ask to make a 95% confidence interval for the mean point average for all the students.

Comment: O.K, no problem. then $95$% is the confidence level. Let me write it out below.

Comment: I expanded on the comment below. Please see if the answer helps.

Comment: Thanks you so much, this helps.

Comment: Glad to help; wish my students agreed with you ;).

Answer (score 0):

O.K: this is one way of doing it: we assume the population is normally-distributed, with mean $2.5$ and we have that $\sigma=0.694$. Then all the possible values of $\mu$ with probability of less than $95$%-or-less, fall within $+/- 1.95$ standard deviations from $2.5$. So we construct the interval $$(2.5-1.95(0.694) ,2.5+1.95(0.694))=(1.13,3.87) $$

Then you need to see if $3.1$ falls within this interval. If so, the value 3.1 has probability larger than $95$% of being observed in this population.

The $p$-value is the probability of observing a value of $3.1$ in a normally-distributed population with mean $2.5$ and $\sigma =0.694$. Look at a standard normal table to see the percentile associated with the $z$-value of $3.1$.

Answer (score 0):

$t = \frac{(\bar{X} - \mu)}{\frac{s}{\sqrt(n)}}$
with df = n-1

here
$s = $0.694$  $
$n = $25$  $
$\bar{X} = 3.1 $
$ \mu = 2.5$
hence
$t = \frac{(3.1-2.5)}{(0.694/\sqrt{(25)})}$
$ t = 4.32276 $
 p-value $= 2P( t >|t|) = 2P(T > 4.32276) $   with df = $24$
$= 0.0002$